# Find the line integral. Have I set this problem up correctly?

Tags: line-integrals

F, the vector field, $ = [xy, x^{2}y^{2}]$

C is a quarter-circle from (2,0) to (0,2) with center (0,0).

So r(t) =  the parametric equation of C $=[2cost(t), 2sin(t)$

$$r'(t) = [-2sin{t}, 2cos{t}]$$

$$F(r(t)) = [4sin(t)cos(t), 4cos^{2}{t} * 4sin^{2}{t}]$$
$$F(r(t)) = [4sin(t)cos(t), 16cos^{2}{t} * sin^{2}{t}]$$

Is this right so far? Then I setup the integral like this?

$$\int_C F(r(t) \cdot r'(t)$$
$$\int_C [4sin(t)cos(t), 16cos^{2}{t} * sin^{2}{t}] \cdot [-2sin{t}, 2cos{t}]$$

Is that right so far? Can someone help me out to the finish? My book says the asnwer is 8/5

Comment: This would be a lot easier to read if you write `\cos t` and `\sin t` rather than `cost` and `sint`

Comment: You are on the right track, all that's left is to compute the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\int_C [4sin(t)cos(t), 16cos^{2}{t} * sin^{2}{t}] \cdot [-2sin{t}, 2cos{t}]
$$
In the parameterized space, $0 \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.
Therefore,
$$
=8(\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 4sin^2(t)cos^3(t)dt-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}sin^2(t)cos(t)dt) \\\\
=8(\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 4sin^2(t)(1-sin^2(t))cos(t)dt-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}sin^2(t)cos(t)dt) 
$$
Let $u=sin(t), du=-cos(t)dt$
$$
=8(4\int_{1}^{0} (u^2-u^4)du-\int_{1}^{0}u^2du) \\
=8(4(-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5})+\frac{1}{3}) \\
=8(-\frac{1}{5})
=-\frac{8}{5}
$$
It seems i'm off by a minus sign but i'll leave that up to you!